# Bar chart that counts rows google sheets / Pandemic-like chart

Tags: google-sheets, google, google-sheets-charts

I have a google form linked to a google sheet (so every time somenone fills the form, a new row is created). I would like to make a chart that count the number of rows each day. In the example shown below, I would like the first bar to have a height of 3, the second 6, then constant until 03/05/2020 where it goes to 16 and so on... Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this :

```
=QUERY(A:A,"SELECT A, count(A) group by A order by A desc")
```

Result :

[image]

Graph :
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I simply added an extra column that counts the total entries to the considered day (simply by adding the day before and the current day). Thx again!